# How is a normal computed for a non-coplanar quad?

Tags: faces, normals

Simple question, if I have a quad with four vertices that are not coplanar how is the normal for the face calculated? I know that there are two distinct ways that the quad can be split into tris, but these two ways of splitting have different topology. How does blender choose which way to partition the quad into tris when rendering and what normal does it use?